# enforcing a ruby gem version

Tags: ruby, heroku, rest-client

I am completely new to ruby, don't know the 1st thing about rvm, gemset etc. Just forced to use a CLI tool (kensa by heroku) written in ruby and facing an issue.

The kensa tool seems to use a gem named rest-client. When I run it it throws an error:

```
/Users/shaharsol/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/restclient/request.rb:163:in `fetch': key not found: :ciphers (KeyError)
```

Some searches suggest that v1.8 of rest-client is too old so I installed v2.0.2. Now when I do a `gem list` I get:

```
rest-client (2.0.2, 1.8.0)
```

When I run kensa again it still used to old version. So I went and modified it `kensa.gemspec` file (which is referred to from `Gemfile`) and to my best understanding told it to use the newer version:

```
s.add_runtime_dependency(%q<rest-client>, "~> 2.0")
```

Yet, when I run kensa again, it still uses the old rest-client 1.8.0!

What am I missing? What am I doing wrong? Or what else is required for the kensa to run with the new rest-client 2.0.2 ???

PS - If my problem doesn't relate at all to changing 1.8.0 => 2.0.2 please tell me what else to do. I really don't care which rest-client version kensa uses, I just need it to run!

Comment: You are chasing the wrong thing.  Kensa depends on 1.8, so keep that.  There's nothing wrong with it. What version of Ruby are you using?

Comment: If you run `irb` you should be able to run this and get a list: `OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext::DEFAULT_PARAMS.fetch(:ciphers)`

Comment: this is the result of `ruby -v`: `ruby 2.4.2p198 (2017-09-14 revision 59899) [x86_64-darwin15]`

Comment: @Joe and when I run the irb command I get: `NameError: uninitialized constant OpenSSL
 from (irb):1
 from /Users/shaharsol/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'`

Comment: sorry you may have to `require openssl` first

Comment: irb response: `KeyError: key not found: :ciphers
 from (irb):3:in `fetch'
 from (irb):3
 from /Users/shaharsol/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'`

Comment: did you build Ruby yourself?  What platform is this?  Something is super strange with your Ruby OpenSSL if `ciphers` is missing.

Comment: You should get something like

`$ ruby -v`
ruby 2.4.3p205 (2017-12-14 revision 61247) [x86_64-darwin16]

`$ irb`
`irb(main):001:0> require 'openssl'`
=> true
`irb(main):002:0> OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext::DEFAULT_PARAMS.fetch(:ciphers)`
=> "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:..."

Comment: This looks like it could be related: https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/3923  (and I use `rbenv`, not `rvm`...)

Comment: Did exactly what was suggested there: https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/3923#issuecomment-280846180 and still no go...

Comment: and still same `KeyError: key not found: :ciphers
 from (irb):2:in `fetch'
 from (irb):2
 from /Users/shaharsol/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'` message in irb. That's after [what i believe was] a ruby reinstall!

Comment: Something's up with your ruby install w/r/t OpenSSL.  I'm not sure what to tell you.

Answer (score -1):

To remove older version of the gem, you have two options:

```
# remove all versions of the gem
gem cleanup rest-client
```

After this, you can do 'bundle install' and only install the version you want.

```
# choose which one you want to remove
gem uninstall rest-client --version 1.8.0
```

After this, you will only have 2.0.2 version.

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks Nabin. Followed your answer and when running the uninstall got this scary message: `You have requested to uninstall the gem:
 rest-client-1.8.0

kensa-3.0.2 depends on rest-client (~> 1.8)
If you remove this gem, these dependencies will not be met.` which also suggests that somewhere somehow kensa still thinks it needs 1.8

Comment: @shaharsol What message did you get?

Comment: @shaharsol Yes, indeed. It seems you need 1.8 version as well.

Comment: @shaharsol Can you try following steps: open Gemfile.lock and change all rest-client versions to the version you want. Then run `bundle install`

Comment: @taitrantuan ran `bundle install`, though the Gemfile.lock *already* contained `rest-client (2.0.2)`, and it didn't matter. It still runs with 1.8

Comment: @shaharsol It works on my machine. There are 2 places on Gemfile.lock contains rest-client, have you changed them all? If you already done, can you run `gem uninstall rest-client` to uninstall all rest-client versions them run `bundle install` again?

Comment: When I run the uninstall it warns me that kensa is dependant on 1.8 and it won't be met if I delete it. In the Gemfile.lock there are 2 places where rest-client appears. One in the `specs` section where it listed `rest-client (~> 2.0)` and one in the `GEM` section where it is listed `rest-client (2.0.2)`